# useful way for coloring 3ds object in opengl

Tags: opengl, c++, blender

I have been working in making plane in blender and it has many materials over than 90 , and now 
I need it in an opengl project with c++  , but as you know if I but the 3ds file the plane color is totally  white so I have to color back all the parts of the plane and it's getting really hard with all the materials I have , any useful thing I can make ? .

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to color objects in OpenGL. You can specify colors as vertex attributes. You can apply textures to objects by supplying texture coordinates and the actual textures. You can write fragment shaders to determine the color programatically. Or you can use a combination of those 3 things (and possibly others).

Does your "3ds" file contain textures or at least the paths of the textures on disk? If so, you can probably load them and use them directly.

If you want a more detailed answer, you'll need to supply more information, such as how you're loading the file, what the file contains, etc. Also, let us know which version of OpenGL you're using, as the answer will depend greatly on that.